# python - Trouble calculating manhatan distance, TypeError

Tags: python, class, gps

So I have a school project where we need to make a few classes for a GPS system.  I'm having an issue figuring out the function dist(self,other): shown at the bottom of my code.  Other definitions later in the project heavily rely on it, but i'm stumped at this point. The dist function calculates the Manhattan distance (x1-x2)+(y1-y2) of a location defined by instance variables **x** and **y**, and another location **other** which is given as a Tuple

```
class GPS_Location:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def __str__(self):
        return '(%s,%s)' % (self.x,self.y)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'GPS_Location(%s,%s)' % (self.x,self.y)
   def __eq__(self,other):
        self.other = other
        if (self.x,self.y) == other:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def dist(self,other):
        self.other = other
        return abs(self.x - (other[0])) + abs(self.y - (other[1])) #TypeError
```

When testing the code, I keep getting "TypeError: 'GPS_Location' object is not iterable".  I have tried so many tweaks, and I just can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add your code as code-formatted text, not as a link to an image.

Comment: You should also add the code that generates the error. What is a `Location` object?

Comment: Side note: why to write `self.other = other` in both `dist` and `__eq__` without ever using it (you call both functions with `other` argument and use `other` in your code)? Or do you use it somewhere else?

Comment: The error is actually "TypeError: 'GPS_Location' object is not iterable".  I must have typed it wrong the first time and left out GPS

Comment: Ok, but the error does not appear without ever calling the method, right? So, how do you call it (literally)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that line 8 is indented by 4 spaces like the rest of the methods.
2. There doesn't seem to be any reason to assign `other` to `self.other` in `__eq__()` and `dist()`.
3. The only other issue you might be having could be related to how you are calling these methods (you mentioned that the argument `other` is just a tuple), this works:

   ```
   x = GPS_Location(1, 1)
   x == (1, 1)
   # True
   x == (2, 2)
   # False
   x.dist((1, 1))
   # 0
   x.dist((2, 2))
   # 2
   ```

If you in fact need to pass a second `GPS_Location` as the `other` argument to `dist`, then it needs to be updated as follows:

```
def dist(self, other):
    return abs(self.x - other.x) + abs(self.y - other.y)
```

Call it like so:

```
x = GPS_Location(1, 1)
y = GPS_Location(2, 2)
x.dist(y)
# 2
```